# How do I import annotations into proto?

Tags: go, proto

I am trying to import annotations into my proto file. I copied the "google" folder to "project / proto/google".

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
```

the path `google / api / annotations.proto` - the project is located.
I am tried use the go mode init and vendor, it didn`t help

In the proto file, only google/protobuf offers autocomplete and that's it, I don't see such a folder in GOPATH

What do I do to make it work?

**Edit 1-**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4JrE.png)

I use

```
protoc -I $GOPATH/src/github.com/jeka2708/test-grpc/proto/ --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative  --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative proto/login.proto
```

Answer (score 1):

`google/api/annotations.proto` is not part of the base standard of include files that comes with the `protoc` compiler distribution (see latest [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/latest)).

To incorporate it in your `protoc` build - simply download the version you need ([latest](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/annotations.proto), you'll also need it's included dependency [http.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto)) - and place it in a directory who's suffix matches the import path i.e.

```
/SOME/DIRECTORY/PATH/google/api/annotations.proto
/SOME/DIRECTORY/PATH/google/api/http.proto
```

The prefix path could be the system default include path (`/usr/include`) e.g.

```
/usr/include/google/api/annotations.proto
/usr/include/google/api/http.proto
```

or you can place in some project directory:

```
/home/user/my_proj/google/api/annotations.proto
/home/user/my_proj/google/api/http.proto
```

and the `protoc` compiler will default to looking in the current working directory - or you can specify custom include paths via the command-line options:

```
Usage: ./protoc [OPTION] PROTO_FILES

Parse PROTO_FILES and generate output based on the options given:
  -IPATH, --proto_path=PATH   Specify the directory in which to search for
                              imports.  May be specified multiple times;
                              directories will be searched in order.  If not
                              given, the current working directory is used.
                              If not found in any of the these directories,
                              the --descriptor_set_in descriptors will be
                              checked for required proto file.
```

Comment: I tried it. I put it in the directory of my project. He doesn't see everything exactly. I edited my question and added an image of the path